# Inducing a map on a sub-polydisc

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

please forgive my title, I don't know what else to call this. 
In trying to prove a certain result, I've come across a technical part that I'm having trouble with.. Suppose that we call the unit polydisc $P$ = $B_{(1,1)}(0)$ = $\{ ( z_{1}, z_{2} ) : \|z_{i}\| < 1 \}$, and for $0 < r < 1$, $P_{r} = B_{(r,r)}(0)$ = $\{ ( z_{1}, z_{2} ) : \|z_{i}\| < r \}$.
If $F$ is a biholomorphism of $P$ onto itself, such that $F(0) = 0$, I'd like to show that $F(P_{r}) \subset P_{r}$.

The Schwarz lemma in several variables that I am aware of applies to this situation to say that $\|f(z)\| \leq \sqrt{2}\|z\|$ for $z \in P$

(please see https://books.google.ca/books?id=eZPCfJlHkXMC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=huybrechts+schwarz+lemma&source=bl&ots=EE0fjefJTp&sig=wRANyd5ghfXouWZR12grjhJcj34&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMI2fTQzPb3xwIVAjOICh1J6gky#v=onepage&q=huybrechts%20schwarz%20lemma&f=false proposition 1.1.36 for details)

The $\sqrt{2}$ is throwing me off.. everything would work out if that was $1/\sqrt{2}$ instead. Furthermore, notice that if we look at the single variable function $F_{1}(z_{1},0) = g(z_{1})$, then $g(0) = 0$ and $g$ maps the unit disc onto itself. By the single variable Schwarz lemma, $\|F_{1}(z_{1},0)\| \leq \| z_{1} \| < r$ as desired, if $\|z_{1}\| < r$ (where $F(z_{1}, z_{2}) = (F_{1}, F_{2} )$ )

Any help?

Thanks!